# How do I delete items from a dictionary

Tags: python

I am copying code I wrote in class for a text adventure assignment however it is not acting the same as the code I wrote in class.

The problem being that my items are not being removed from my "roomitems" like they should be.

I am only a beginner so please try and keep it simple for me :)

```
rooms = ["hallEnt", "hallMid", "snowRoom", "giantNature", "strangeWall", "riverBank"]
roomDirections = {
    "hallEnt":{"e":"hallMid"},
    "hallMid":{"s":"snowRoom", "e":"giantNature", "w":"hallEnt"},
    "snowRoom":{"n":"hallMid"},
    "giantNature":{"s":"strangeWall", "e":"riverBank", "w":"hallMid"},
    "strangeWall":{"s":"hallOuter", "e":"riverBank", "n":"giantNature"},
    "riverBank":{"e":"lilyOne", "w":"giantNature"},
    "lilyOne":{"e":"lilyTwo", "w":"riverBank", "n":"riverBank", "s":"riverBank"},
    "lilyTwo":{"e":"riverBank", "w":"lilyThree", "n":"riverBank", "s":"riverBank"},
    "lilyThree":{"e":"riverBank", "w":"lilyFour", "n":"riverBank", "s":"riverBank"},
    "lilyFour":{"e":"riverBank", "w":"treasureRoom", "n":"riverBank", "s":"riverBank"},
    "treasureRoom":{"w":"hallEnt"},
}

roomDescriptions = {
    "hallEnt":"The hallway continues east, the cave opening is to the north, there is an opening in the south wall, but its too high to reach, there are some snowboots on the ground.",
    "hallMid":"To the east the hallway grows dark, there is a corridor to the south",
    "snowRoom":"The room is a dead end except for a lit lamp on the ground",
    "giantNature":"To the east you see a river, to the south is a wall with some strange lines on it",
    "strangeWall":"It appears to be just a wall, there are some old lines on the wall but you can't make them out.",
    "riverBank":"The river has giant lilypads floating on its surface, however there is only one safe path across them, jump on the wrong lilypad and you will go through it and be swept back to the riverbank.",
    "lilyOne":"The lilypads all look the same, you can only guess which is the right direction",
    "lilyTwo":"The lilypads all look the same, you can only guess which is the right direction",
    "LilyThree":"The lilypads all look the same, you can only guess which is the right direction",
    "LilyFour":"The lilypads all look the same, you can only guess which is the right direction",
    "treasureRoom":"There is nothing in the room except for a pedistal with priceless treasures on top of it.",
}

roomEntrance = {
    "hallEnt":"You are standing in the hallway entrance.",
    "hallMid":"You walk to the middle of the hallway.",
    "snowRoom":"You are standing in a room as white as can be, and it is snowing inside the room.",
    "giantNature":"You walk into a gigantic forest with a river running through the middle",
    "strangeWall":"You walk over to the strange wall.",
    "riverBank":"You walk right up to the edge of the river.",
    "lilyOne":"You jump onto the first lilypad.",
    "lilyTwo":"You jump onto the second lilypad.",
    "lilyThree":"You jump onto the third lilypad.",
    "lilyFour":"You jump onto the fourth lilypad.",
    "treasureRoom":"You land safely on the far bank of the river.",
}

dirs = ["north","south", "east", "west", "n", "s", "e", "w",]

roomItems = {
    "hallEnt":"snowboots",
    "snowRoom":"lamp",
    "treasureRoom":"treasure",
    }

currentRoom = "hallEnt"
invItems = []


print("You are standing in a dark cave entrance")

while True:
    playerInput = input("What do you want to do? ")
    playerInput = playerInput.lower()
    if playerInput == "quit":
        break

    elif playerInput == "look":
        print(roomDescriptions[currentRoom])

    elif playerInput in dirs:
        playerInput = playerInput[0]
        if playerInput in roomDirections[currentRoom]:
            currentRoom = roomDirections[currentRoom][playerInput]
            print(roomEntrance [currentRoom])
        else:
            print("You can't go that way")


    elif playerInput == "lookdown":
        print ("You see", roomItems[currentRoom])




    elif playerInput == "inventory" or playerInput == "inv":
        print (invItems)

    else:
        if playerInput in roomItems[currentRoom]:
            print("picked up", playerInput)
            invItems.append(playerInput)
            for i in range(0, len(roomItems[currentRoom]):
                if playerInput == roomItems[currentRoom][i]:
                    del roomItems[currentRoom][i]
                    break

        elif playerInput in invItems:
            print("dropped", playerInput)
            roomItems[currentRoom].append (playerInput)
            for i in range (0, len(invItems)):
                if playerInput == invItems[i]:
                    del invItems[i]
                    break



        else:
            print("I don't understand")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by how it loops through the room items it seems like it's expecting the room items to be a list of strings. Now they're just plain strings.  Maybe the items should look more like this:

```
roomItems = {
    "hallEnt": ["snowboots"],
    "snowRoom": ["lamp"],
    "treasureRoom": ["treasure"],
}
```

It's also worth checking out the list `remove` method, because it lets you remove things from a list without having to write a loop by hand. For instance:

```
invItems.remove(playerInput)
```

It's of course OK to write that loop by hand once to understand how to do it, but after that one time, using the built-in methods makes your larger programs easier to read.

**Edit:** There's also a closing parenthesis missing on this line:

```
for i in range(0, len(roomItems[currentRoom]):
```

I found this out by running the script. Does your system not report the line number for errors?

Comment: originally I did have it written as per your first suggestion, this gave me syntax errors everywhere, and it will add items to my "invItems" just wont remove them from "roomItems"

Comment: @kebab: Then you didn't have it exactly as I suggested because what I suggested does not have syntax errors. Maybe you forgot to close a bracket when you wrote it.

Comment: that part was 100% right all brackets closed, trust me, im sure the syntax errors were caused by something further along in the code but im too new to coding i cant tell

Comment: okay, it was a combination of that missing parenthesis, AND, the missing [] in my list of items, items are now removing as they should, thank you very much you've no idea the relief i just felt (my deadline is approaching and i was super stuck)